# how to create unique ID for pairs

Tags: python

I have pandas dataframe that store the relationship of two customers like below. How do I create a unique ID for associated customers?

Assuming there are tons of thousands of customers. The customer ID are completed random numbers which are not classified as prefix 'A' and 'B' in the example presented. The prefix is just for explaining the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['A1', 'A1'], 
        ['A1', 'A2'], 
        
        ['A2', 'A1'],
        ['A2', 'A3'],
        
        ['A3', 'A2'],
        ['A3', 'A4'],
        
        ['A4', 'A3'],
        ['A4', 'A5'],
        
        ['B1', 'B1'], 
        ['B1', 'B2'], 
        
        ['B2', 'B1'],
        ['B2', 'B3'],
        
        ['B3', 'B2'],
        ['B3', 'B4'],
        
        ['B4', 'B3'],
        ['B4', 'B5']
        ]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cust_1', 'cust_2'])
  
# print dataframe.
df
```

The end results should like below:
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those IDs don't seem very unique...

Comment: What is the logic behind calculating the ID?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only A and B, you can simply see the starting point to calculate the ID.

```
In [12]: df['Unique_ID'] = df['cust_1'].map(lambda x: 'ID1' if x.startswith('A')
    ...:  else 'ID2')                                                           

In [13]: df                                                                     
Out[13]: 
   cust_1 cust_2 Unique_ID
0      A1     A1       ID1
1      A1     A2       ID1
2      A2     A1       ID1
3      A2     A3       ID1
4      A3     A2       ID1
5      A3     A4       ID1
6      A4     A3       ID1
7      A4     A5       ID1
8      B1     B1       ID2
9      B1     B2       ID2
10     B2     B1       ID2
11     B2     B3       ID2
12     B3     B2       ID2
13     B3     B4       ID2
14     B4     B3       ID2
15     B4     B5       ID2
```

Here if first element in group is A, id is ID1 as shown in fig, if it is B, id is ID2 as shown.

Comment: sorry I should have clarify that. Assuming there are tons of thousands of customers. The customer ID are completed random numbers which are not classified as prefix 'A' and 'B' in the example presented. That was just for explaining the problem, but thanks for answering.

Comment: @Michael you should post the actual data and expected results. You won't get helpful answers if you give irrelevant examples.